# @JavaScriptInterface to work with both ICS and JB projects

Tags: javascript, android, annotations, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am running into an issue with [@JavaScriptInterface annotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) requirement to support api 15 (ICS) and 17 (JB). I have an Android library project which is shared by two application projects. The library project contains WebView-related classes with [javascript interfaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). For the application projects, one of them targets api 15 while the other targets api 17. This is our requirement/contraint since we use a customized Android SDK.

The problem is how to make the library project works with both application projects. If the library project targets api 15, it cannot have @JavaScriptInterface annotation which means javascript callback will not work with api 17 application project.

On the other hand, if the library project targets api 17, it will not work with api 15 application project because application project cannot link with library project with higher api level.

Any suggestion on how to have the javascript interface classes in the library project work with both api 15 and api 17 application projects?

Comment: One approach that I was looking into was using something along the line of dependency injection. The library project uses custom annotation where with api 17 project it injects @JavaScriptInterface while with api 15 project it injects a noop. However, this does not seem possible because annotation in JDK 6 does not support inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestion on how to have the javascript interface classes in the library project work with both api 15 and api 17 application projects?

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to be less than 17, as `@JavaScriptInterface` is not applied until you set `android:targetSdkVersion` to 17 or higher. Then, simply skip `@JavaScriptInterface`.

Comment: This does not work. The class is in the library project which is shared by api15 and api17 application projects. When building the api17 application project, it expects the class in the library project to have @JavaScriptInterface, regardless of library project's targetSdkVersion. While it builds successfully, javascript calls do not work.

Comment: @ejel: Sorry, I meant that you should set `android:targetSdkVersion` to be less than 17 on the application project, not on the library.

Comment: The api17 application project needs to access some api17-specific APIs (some of them are provided as a custom Add-on SDK tight to api17). Thus the project requires targetSdkVersion = 17.

Comment: @ejel: "Thus the project requires targetSdkVersion = 17" -- you need to learn the difference between the build target (i.e., what `android.jar` you are compiling against, which controls whether you can "access some api17-specific APIs") and `android:targetSdkVersion` (which does not). While they both contain "target" in their name, they are independent concepts. Since this is a one character change in your manifest file, you might consider actually trying it.

Comment: You were right--I was confused between the build target and `android:targetdkVersion`. Setting `targetSdkVersion` to 15 would cause api15 compatibility mode to be applied, thus the `@JavaScriptInterface` requirement does not take effect.